# Basic Variables Not Adding!!! (A Section Of My Code)

Tags: python, variables

```
number = 1

p1 = 0
p2 = 0

while number <5:
  gametype = input("Do You Want To Play 1 Player Or 2 Player")
  if gametype == "2":
    player1areyouready = input("Player 1, Are You Ready? (Yes Or No)") #Asking If Their Ready
  if player1areyouready == "yes": #If Answer is Yes
    print ("Great!")
  else: #If Answer Is Anything Else
    print ("Ok, Ready When You Are! :)")
  player2areyouready = input("Player 2, Are You Ready? (Yes Or No)") #Asking If Their Ready
  if player2areyouready == "yes":
   print ("Great, Your Both Ready!") #If Both Are Ready
  else:
    print ("Ok, Ready When You Are! :)")

  print ("Lets Get Right Into Round 1!") #Start Of Round 1
  game1 = input("Player 1, What Is Your Decision? (Rock, Paper or Scissors?) (No Capitals Please)") #Asking Player 1 For their Decision
  game2 = input("Player 2, What Is Your Decision? (Rock, Paper or Scissors?) (No Capitals Please)") #Asking Player 2 For Their Decision

  if game1 == game2:
   print("Tie!") 
   p1 + 0
   p2 + 0
   print ("Player 1's Score Currently Is...")    
   print (p1)

   print ("Player 2's Score Currently Is...") 
   print (p2) #I'm Programming A Rock, Paper Scissors Game
```

In This Rock Paper Scissors Game, I'm Finding Trouble With My Score Variables. For Some Reason The Way I Programmed My Code Means That My Score Won't Add Up. Please Help :)
Thanks In Advance

Comment: You need to do `p1 += some_score` to actually change `p1`. You can't just do `p1 + some_score` because it will not save the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is a tie, you don't need to update the score. However:

```
if game1 != game2:
    p1 = p1 + score # Replace score with a number or assign score a value
    p2 = p2 + score
```

Currently score is not being updated, because doing `p1 + score` will not update `p1`'s value. You need to reassign to it. So do `p1 = p1 + score` or `p1 += score`

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on my IDLE I get all kinds of problems. That aside if all you are trying to do is add to a variable and its all numbers then you can do

```
# Put this at the end of the if statement where player one is the winner.
p1 += 1 
# Put this at the end of the if statement where player two is the winner.
p2 += 1
```

All this is doing is adding 1 to the current number in the variable.

It should be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added anything to the scores.  First, your only statement dealing with the scores is an expression, not an assignment.  You need to keep the value by storing the result back in the variable, such as

```
number = number + 1
```

which you can shorten to

```
number += 1
```

Second, you've added 0 to p1 and p2.  Even if you store the results, the value doesn't change.

---

**REPAIR**

You will need to determine which player wins, and then increment that player's score.  I won't write the detailed code for you, but consider this:

```
if game1 == game2:
    print ("Tie!")
elif game1 == "Rock" and game2 == "Scissors":
    print ("Player 1 wins!")
    p1 += 1
elif game1 == "Rock" and game2 == "Paper":
    print ("Player 2 wins!")
    p2 += 1

print ("Player 1's Score Currently Is...", p1)    
print ("Player 2's Score Currently Is...", p2)
```

Do you see how that works?  Update a score only when a player wins a round.  Of course, you'll want to find a more general way of picking the winner, rather than working through all six winning combinations, but that's an exercise for the student.  :-)